# What is a half step down from a song in Gbm on piano?

Tags: piano, transposition

When a singer asks to tune a song a half step down from Gbm would that be Fminor or Gb?

Comment: Just to clarify one point that might be confusing you: the "m" at the end of "Gbm" means "minor." It tells you nothing about the starting note of the key, just about the "mode," the pattern of steps that make up the scale. If there is no lower-case "m," then a key abbreviation like "Gb" is assumed to be major. A major or minor scale can start on the same note; changing the mode doesn't "lower" the song, it transforms it into [something very different](https://youtu.be/g_TEOuyPDNo).

Comment: Do you really mean Gbm - G flat minor - or did you mean F sharp minor? G flat minor's (theoretical) key signature is horrific, and music in G flat minor is nearly impossible to read. (I once read a passage in C flat minor using an A flat minor key signature. That was also nearly impossible to read.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means F minor.

Singers frequently change the key of (transpose) a song in order to best fit their vocal range.

Changing to Gb major would be a change of mode, which would entirely change the character of the music.

The below video is timed to a performance of the Beatles's "Here Comes the Sun", first in major, then shifted to minor.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if the original key was G♭m - F♯m is far more the common way to call it. But you wouldn't change the key of any song from minor to major - or vice versa, just to suit someone's range. In fact, merely dropping a semitone is unusual. if it's that awkward to sing in G♭m, Em could be even better! (And probably easier to play...)

So, basic premise - if the original is in minor, change key to another minor, if major, new key needs to be also major.